# re-organize data stored in a csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, storage

I have successfully downloaded my data from a given url and for storing it into a csv file I used the following code:

```
    fx = open(destination_url, "w") #write data into a file
    for line in lines: #loop through the string
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close() # close the file object
    return
```

What happened is that the data is stored but not in separate lines. As one can see in the snapshot - the data is not separated into a different lines when I use the '\n'.

Every separate line of data that I wanted seems to be separated via the  '\r'  (marked by yellow) on the same cell in the csv file. Here is a snip: [image: snap shot for the \r in the data].

[image]

I know I am missing something here but can I get some pointers with regards to rearranging each line that ends with a \r into a separate line ?

I hope I have made myself clear. 
Thanks
~V

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. From your code, it seems like you're trying to open an URL and write to it.  Did you already downloaded the csv file which you're trying to open it and write to another file?  Or you're trying to open an csv file and write newline to it?

Comment: 1. To make myself clearer - I have a given link and then I download what ever is there into a csv file. When I do that - this lines are not arranged properly because of some reason. 
2. Does it make a difference if the link has a csv and then I save to a csv ? I ask because this particular case there is one csv file among others.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in csv format but your overall logic is wrong.  You're opening a file object, loop through the line from some string (not from the destination_url), and write to the file object. Let's take a step back, and update your question with what kind of output you're getting when doing:

with open (csv_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print (line)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method call writelines

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm

some example is in the given link you can try that first in reality it should work we need the format of the data (what is inside the element) during each iteration print that out if the above method does not work